# In "Chat", can users create their own rooms?

Tags: support, chat

I've asked my question in the title :).

Additionally, how much reputation will I need to do so, and what guidelines are linked with this?

Comment: Follow-up post by OP: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90796/no-button-to-create-a-new-room-in-chat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, any user with at least 100 reputation gets the [privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms) to create new chat rooms.

As the privilege page says:

> ### When should I create a new chat room?
>
> When you find yourself wanting to have an extended conversation about a topic that is not covered by one of the existing chat rooms, you should create a new room for it.

---

And finally at 1000 reputation you can create gallery chat rooms - these are rooms where you (as the owner) can decide who can and cannot talk.

Comment: You have answered the question most completely out of those who have, so the answer goes to you.  It won't let me award it for another two minutes, so IOU 15 reputation :P.

Comment: @cbroughton, in that case, can I just warn you in advance that I charge ~1893% interest per minute...

Comment: If only Haha.

Comment: @cbroughton Oh well, worth a shot I suppose. ;P

Answer (score 5):

You can create chatrooms with [100](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms) reputation.

You can create a gallery chatroom with [1000](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms) reputation.

Answer (score 4):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms

For those too lazy to click the link: it requires 100 reputation to create chat rooms both here and in the main SO site. :)