# No button to create a new room in chat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, chat, privileges

Please see the screenshot below, I do not see the button or link to create a room anywhere...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKGqN.png

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKGqN.png]

Comment: Related post by OP: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90788/in-chat-can-users-create-their-own-rooms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should see one now (on the main room index, as Grace Note points out). Chat required a reputation of 101 to create a room instead of 100 (`>` vs `>=`), and you are at the single point in your reputation career where this actually matters :)

Comment: In other words, I could have fixed it by voting up one of your posts, but I decided to do really fix the bug ;)

Comment: You could always do both! (;

Answer (score 5):

You're on the [search page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=), not on the [main rooms page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). Click the link at the top that says "X rooms active" (14 in the case of your screenshot), and that'll provide a full room listing. At the bottom right corner, there should be [the button to create a new chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new).

Or, if entering URLs is to your fancy over finding a button, you can also head to `https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new`, substituting `chat.meta.stackoverflow` or `chat.stackexchange` as appropriate.

Comment: Erm, that page is both empty, and looks like this: http://imgur.com/YshoF  Even upon clicking the all tab, I still see no button or link.

Comment: @cbroughton The page was empty because you hadn't created any rooms yet. As for why you don't have the button, though... not sure. Why happens when you directly visit the URL for the new button? It's the last hyperlink in my answer, to save you the trouble of typing it out.

Comment: @cbroughton It looks like you have exactly 100 reputation on SO. Did you just reach that level a few minutes ago? SO caches things all over the place, so the right answer for you _may_ simply be "wait an hour or two."